# I'm trying to make a discord bot that DM's a random user and It either DM's me only or I get an error

Tags: discord, discord.js

This is my code and It seems the random user selection is broken although it works completely fine in another command I have that pings a random user

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}command`) {
    
    const userList = message.guild.members.cache.array();
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * userList.length)
    var dm = userList[randomNumber]
                         
    console.log(dm.user.id)
    
    dm.send("123");
}
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user

I get it whenever the bot selects it's own user id instead of mine

Comment: thats normal, you need to add a check if the user is a bot. I'll write you an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, so the code you have written works just fine. The problem is that your bot cannot send a message to its self. There is a very easy solution to this. Just check if the selected member is a bot and `return` if that's the case. *Note: I put your random number inside the array field of the `userList`.*

```
const userList = message.guild.members.cache.array();
var dm = userList[Math.floor(Math.random() * userList.length)];
if (dm.user.bot) return;

console.log(dm.user.username);

dm.send("123");
```

*Note: If you only have yourself and the bot on your test server then this will only ever send a DM to you. In that case I would recommend getting a secondary account and inviting some friends to the test server.*

Comment: This code works better but Im still running into the issue of the bot only dming me even though there are like 10 people on the server

Comment: have you asked the other people to tell you if they get a DM? also it's random so there is a chance you'll get selected more then once.

Comment: I have asked them and it seems that they only get a DM whenever they use the command. Also the console only shows my username

Comment: then there is something really weird going on, I can confirm that it works on my test server and everyone is being messaged.

Comment: Also, it is random and only one at a time. Try to use the command multiple times, at least 10 times. In addition to that, you can console.log whenever the bot check kicks in. Just so you know how often a bot gets selected

Comment: I just restarted the bot and it seems to be working now. Weird,

Comment: oh yes, you need to restart the bot after every change to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the members intent? The members list only shows you and the bot if you don't have that intent enabled. Read the [docs for intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents) for more information.

Comment: Just tried that and it doesn't seem to be working sadly.

Comment: are you sure you enabled the members intent in Discord's Dev Portal? (in addition to enabling it in your code)

Comment: Yes I did do that I think there might be some other issue